# postgresql migration: Dirty database version xxx. Fix and force version

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, database-migration, harbor

Failed to upgrade schema, error: "Dirty database version 3. Fix and force version."
failed to migrate the database, error: Dirty database version 3. Fix and force version.

I was trying to connect harbor to an external Postgres Database within the same Kubernetes Cluster. I deployed both using Helm charts.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Without any code it's a little hard to tell what might be going wrong, but if you're trying to update your database engine or deploy prebuilt software like Harbor, those aren't really the sorts of programming-related tasks that are on-topic for Stack Overflow, and another site like [sf] might be more appropriate.